# String.Format for numbers

Tags: c#, string

I want to display floats between -10^7 to 10^7 with spaces every three digits, both for units and for decimals. 
So, -1234.56789 should be displayed as "-1 234.567 89" (space between 1 and 2 and between 7 and 8).
If I use the code below, and I try to print -234.56, I get a space between minus sign and 2. Is there a better way to deal with this rather than checking if there is a space after the sign and deleting it?

```
string.Format("{0:### ### ##0.000 00}", fValue);
```

Comment: `string.Format(new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo { NumberGroupSeparator=" " }, "{0:#,0.000 00}", fValue)`

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the trick :)